# Recover Windows 7 partition overwritten with Linux installation

Tags: windows, partitioning

I installed Linux Mint over my Windows drive, that was supposed install on my external hard disk.

In Windows 7, that drive is invisible and is showing as Linux when I enter `fdisk -l`.

How can I restore all the directories that were on this drive?

Comment: Don't you have a backup? Did you read all the warnings about actually *erasing* the Windows partition when you went to install Linux Mint?

Comment: You might be able to use recovery software but honestly there is 0% chance ALL your files can be recovered.  Even if your files can be recovered the installation is toast.

Answer (score 1):

It's gone. The best you can do is try some file recovery, but depending upon how much Linux actually overwrote data, you'll probably not get much useful back.